# Can I upgrade from 1.8.1.0 to 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2.2.4

Can I upgrade from 1.8.1.0 to 2.4?
Two questions:

1. Is it possible to jump upgrades, therefore upgrade from Magento 1.8.1.0 directly to Magento 2.4?
2. Are there any detailed instructions on how to get this done?

I am currently using Fastcomet shared Hosting.

Comment: Yes. Check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Comment: i do not have the root access

Answer (score 0):

You have to set both (M1 and M2) database on same server.
**and need to run below steps/commands.**

Install Magento 2 Data Migration Tool via Composer
Before you start the tool installation, make sure that the version of Magento 2 store and Data Migration Tool match.

For example, if you are using Magento version 2.2.0, you must install the Data Migration Tool version 2.2.0.

If you don’t know the version of your store, navigate to the root directory of Magento 2 via SSH and enter the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Update the location of the Data Migration Tool package in the composer.json file to make it work. For that, run the below two commands:

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<version>
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<version>
```

In the above command,  refers to the tool version that is the same as that of your Magento 2 version.

For example, the above commands for Magento version 2.2.0 will look like this:

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.0
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.0
```

You’ll need to enter your developer authentication keys. Go to the Magento Marketplace, login, navigate to your profile and click Access Keys under My Products section.

Enter the username, i.e., public key and password, i.e., private key. You may create new keys using Create a New Access Key button.

That’s all for the installation of Data Migration Tool in Magento 2 store.

Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool
The following directories will contain mapping and configuration files for the Data Migration Tool.

```
<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource
It contains configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open Source platform.

<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce
```

The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.

```
<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce

<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
```

The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.

Before you migrate any settings and data, you must create a config.xml file in the relevant directory. For example, if you are performing data migration from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open Source platform, navigate to the <Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<Magento 1.x version> directory and rename config.xml.dist to config.xml.

Next, open config.xml in a code editor and specify the following:

```
<source>
    <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</destination>
<options>
    <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>
</options>
<source>
    <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</destination>
<options>
    <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>
</options>
```

Here,  has the database information of Magento 1 and  has the relevant database information of Magento 2. <crypt_key> is mandatory and needs to be filled prior to run. It is the encryption key of Magento 1 store and can be found in the <Magento 1 root dir>/app/etc/local.xml file, within the  tag.

Finally, save the config.xml.

Migrate Settings Using Magento 2 Data Migration Tool
Magento 2 Data Migration Tool settings include stores, system configurations such as shipping, payment, tax settings, etc.

According to the Magento Data Migration Order, you should migrate settings first. Navigate to your Magento 2 root directory via SSH terminal and run the following command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset <path to your config.xml>


php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset <path to your config.xml>
where <path to your config.xml> would be vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<Magento 1.x version>/config.xml.
```

I have used –reset argument in the above command which forces the Data Migration Tool to start from the beginning.

The success message is displayed once the settings are over.

Migrate Data Using Magento 2 Data Migration Tool
Data migration from Magento 1 platform to Magento 2 platform includes products, categories, orders, customers, wish lists, ratings, etc.

To migrate data, run the following CLI command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset <path to your config.xml>


php bin/magento migrate:data --reset <path to your config.xml>
```

The tool saves its current progress. If an error occurs, it stops the process and resumes from the last known good state.
The success message is displayed on completion of data migration.

That was all about how to migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2!
Mark as a solution if you think it help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to the latest version. To avoid any mistakes during the upgrade you can refer to this guide of Magento: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html